# How to call update request using exact online API

Tags: exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

i am using exact online PHP SDK. i am able to create record using POST Request.

How to send update request to update SalesOrder DeliveryDate using Orderid?

Comment: What have you tried and based upon what code? Remember to send along primary key (guid)

Comment: Hello,
I want update the account record using API, anybody please tell how i can update the existing account record. I am using "update" function, but i do not understand, how i can send the "guid" as parameter to update function. Anybody help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Please consult developer site of exact online. The documentation clearly describes what to do. If not working please list your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find below example to update request in exact online

```
$salesorderline               = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\SalesOrderLine($connection);

       $s                     = $salesorderline->find('xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx');
       $s->Notes              = 'mahamood';
       $s->DeliveryDate       = '2018-08-02 08:30:00.000000';
       $s->update();
```